# IPTables packet count in INPUT chain doesn't match with sub-chain

Tags: iptables

On my server, I have three rules, for simplicity:

```
iptables -t mangle -N RATE-LIMIT
iptables -t mangle -A RATE-LIMIT -m hashlimit --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-upto 100/sec --hashlimit-burst 20 --hashlimit-name conn_rate_limit -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A RATE-LIMIT -j DROP
iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25565 ! -i lo -j RATE-LIMIT
```

This works for me as it should, but I was wondering about the following verbose output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 11M packets, 921M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
5699K  264M RATE-LIMIT  tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25565

...

Chain RATE-LIMIT (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
3060K  158M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: up to 100/sec burst 20 mode srcip
84990 3882K DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

The first rule matches every packet which is below 100 pps from a specific source IP, if it is below, it should `RETURN` back to `INPUT` and continue there. The second rule just drops every packet which is over this limit, and should basically act as a default policy for this chain.

In the `INPUT` chain, there are about 5.700k packets which jumped into my `RATE-LIMIT` chain. But if I add both rules in my `RATE-LIMIT` chain together, I get a number a lot smaller. From my understanding they should add up to 5.700k.

Why are those two numbers not equal?

Comment: you could use atomic zeroing of the counters (iptables -Z ...) and check again

Comment: @A.B I did zero it out before asking the question here, same result